# django easy pdf can't display include static files (css/ images)

Tags: django, pdf

I am trying to include some images and css into my pdf using django-easy-pdf, however they aren't showing up.

```
getFile '/static/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.css' '...\\mysite\\__dummy__' '...\\mysite\\__dummy__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\xhtml2pdf\context.py", line 828, in _getFileDeprecated
    nv = self.pathCallback(name, relative)
  File "...\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\easy_pdf\rendering.py", line 35, in fetch_resources
    path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.STATIC_URL, ""))
  File "...\Python\Python36-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 75, in join
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
line 0, msg: getFile %r %r %r, fragment:
```

My template file:

```
{% load static %}
<link href="{% static '/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

my folder structure:

```
mysite
- mysite
- app
    -static
```

The static files are working when serving normal webpages, but not in the pdf. Any suggestions?

Comment: `weasyprint.HTML` & `weasyprint.CSS` for the CSS files, and `base64.b64encode` for displaying images. theses modules will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://github.com/nigma/django-easy-pdf/issues/16) Thread, Django-easy-pdf can render images from local `file://` or remote `http/https` urls using `WeasyPrint`. This means you are going to edit your settings file for this setup to work in harmony with django-site. I modified demo app to illustrate this. clone/pull [django-easy-pdf-demo-app](https://github.com/kinyuajasonmuriki/django-easy-pdf-demo-app.git)
 for the modified app.